# How to get Sample count per thread in Jmeter5.1

Tags: jmeter

[Need to count samples generated in thread level. I am using 8 thread groups and each thread group contains multiple transaction controller and each transaction controller contains multiple requests. Problem is here that I am able to get the samples to count for each transaction controller but not for thread level.
I am using 8 ultimate thread group in my test plan for load test executing for 1hr.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhRZC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You could consider adding [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) somewhere to your [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers)'s name

The function will be evaluated in the runtime and resolved into current thread (virtual user) number.

This way you will be able to see how many Samplers did this or that thread execute in a [listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) of your choice, i.e. in [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report)

[image]

Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction/) article for more information on JMeter Functions concept.

Comment: hi Dmitri T,Added linked image with above description. What you told i implemented already but my requirement to get total Sample count for particular Thread group as marked in picture. Please click on description to open the image. Thanks